Forest plot to show results in a observational restrospective cohort study
I have to present my study as a poster and, in order to make my results more visual, I thought it was a good idea to report them as a forest plot. However, it is ok to use a forest plot to report the crude odds ratio (obtained using uni-variable binary logistic regression) or can this type of graphs only be used in meta-analysis?

Some people call them effect plots outside meta-analysis.

You can. I have done it in peer-reviewed work such as Figure 1 at https://doi.org/10.1177/19485506231162401.
If you're an R user, there's a number of packages that call these "coefficient plots" or coefplot() for short. The popular package {arm} has a function for this. There's even a package called {coefplot}. How I make mine is by using emmeans::emmeans() to get point estimates and 95% confidence intervals, coerce that to a data.frame, and do {ggplot2} from there.
I also use these plots for best-worst scaling (i.e., MaxDiff) results. I recommend them in a vignette for my package {bwsTools} (for an applied example, see page 8 here).

Mark, could you check your doi id?

@MarkWhite I took the liberty of correcting the DOI, as the link was pointing to an error page.
